# React context path in WAR

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jakarta-ee, war

I'm using *create react app* with `npm run build` command to build the React project, and copy the build folder content under *webapp* of the WAR project.

The problem is, the context path is omitted when *index.html* tries to retrieve javascript and other static resources from the server. How do I make react aware of the context path? Further, I wouldn't like to hard code the context path on the React project.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to add following line in the *package.json*

```
"homepage": "."
```

Not sure why this seemingly redundant property is needed. Nevertheless, it enables the correct behavior with any context path

Answer (score 3):

`create-react-app` has good documentation so, I think this is what you are looking for

[Serving the Same Build from Different Paths](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths)

please go though above link, It will solve your issue, thanks.